# Task database error in App Insight

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I am having an issue with Application Insight reporting about exceptions with EF context while saving to database.

[image]

```
private async Task SendAsync(IEmailDataModel model)
{
    await _emailHelper.SendAsync(model.To, model.Subject, model.Body);

    /* send messages */
    var logEmail = new LogEmail
    {
        UserSignatureId = GetUserSignature(model.To),
        LogTaskId = model.LogTaskId,
        Type = (int)model.Type,
        Subject = model.Subject,
        From = _defaultConfig.SupportEmailAddress,
        To = model.To,
        Content = model.Body,
        CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
    };

    _unit.Repository<LogEmail>().Insert(logEmail);
    await _unit.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

How am I suppose to debug this? I am using WebJobs with TimerTrigger.

Comment: unrelated: i see that the dates in your search window are all 1/1/0001 midnight.  what local/date settings do you have on your machine, so i can track down and fix that part not showing you the right date?  you can either comment here or email me directly at jgardner @ microsoft

Comment: it's GMT+1 local settings

Comment: if you go to tools -> extensions and updates, what version is the "Developer Analytics Tools" extension?  i'm *presuming* it is 5.2.x or older, i believe this is fixed in things that are 5.200.x or newer.  hypothetically.

Answer (score 0):

If App Insights is telling you this exception occurred, it's because the exception is really occurring.

Chances are, *somewhere in the stack*, whoever calls `SendAsync` isn't awaiting that, or farther and farther back, someone isn't calling await on one of these async methods at some point.

So when the change is rejected (which the inner exception says it was, for validation reasons), nobody is around to catch it and tell anyone about it, so the finalizer is throwing the exception that nobody handled.

And application insights is registered to log unhandled exceptions, so it is showing you exceptions that you otherwise might not be aware of.